# Selenium TimeoutException: Message using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, webdriverwait

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
                    
URL = 'https://gemelnet.cma.gov.il/views/dafmakdim.aspx'
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(2)


review=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='knisa']")))
review.click()

table=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='Aaaa89455bbfe4387b92529246ea52dc6114']//font"))).text()
print(table)
```

I am trying to extract the table but they give me `raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:` how I solve these error any recommendation.
Kindly tell me what mistake I will be doing this is page link https://gemelnet.cma.gov.il/views/dafmakdim.aspx

[image]

```
   table
```

[image]

Comment: //div[@class='Aaaa89455bbfe4387b92529246ea52dc6114']//font selector doesn't exist. Because you use webdriver wait instead of implicit wait, you didin't get element not found exception.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues you need to improve here:

1. The `Aaaa89455bbfe4387b92529246ea52dc6114` class you trying to use is a dynamic value. This can't be used as a locator.
2. The first element you clicking to enter the system - you should wait for element clickability, not only visibility. These conditions are almost similar, but since you are going to **click** the element clickability should be checked. Visibility is normally used when we are going to extract the text form that element.
3. No need to add `time.sleep(2)` before `review=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='knisa']")))`
4. You can apply click directly on the web element object returned by `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='knisa']")))`, no need to store it into `review` temporary variable.
5. The table you trying to print initially presents "Loading" content. So, to overcome this problem I'm waiting for one of it columns to appear , add some more delay and then get the entire table text.

Not ideally, but the following is worked:

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://gemelnet.cma.gov.il/views/dafmakdim.aspx"
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='knisa']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[contains(.,'קרנות השתלמות')]")))
time.sleep(2)
table = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='ReportViewer1_fixedTable']"))).text
print(table)
```

The output is:

```
30/11/2022
(30/11/2022)
סה"כ נכסי הקופות - לפי סוג קופה
(במיליוני ש"ח)
נכון לסוף אוקטובר 2022
תשואה שנתית
סה"כ נכסים
קופ"ג להשקעה- חסכון לילד
קופ"ג להשקעה
מטרה אחרת
מרכזית לפיצויים
קרנות השתלמות
תגמולים ואישית לפיצויים
שנת דיווח
   ---   
648,227
14,480
34,775
946
10,806
303,352
283,869
2022
12.33%
688,304
14,441
34,409
1,043
12,370
321,477
304,565
2021
4.58%
579,438
10,997
20,172
950
12,022
272,631
262,666
2020
11.77%
511,987
---
---
933
13,463
250,174
247,416
2019
התשואה הממוצעת בענף קופות גמל
-6.66%
ב- 12 חודשים האחרונים עמדה על
```